How to implement Dotnet Isolated Azure Function on Alpine using .net8?
I have an Azure Functions project built with .NET 6 that is currently running on Kubernetes with a Debian-based OS. I'm migrating this project to .NET 8 and need it to run on an Alpine machine. I've updated all my code to follow the .NET 8 isolated worker model, and everything works fine locally and with a specific Dockerfile setup:
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated:4-dotnet-isolated8.0 AS base
    WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
    EXPOSE 8080
    
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
    ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
    WORKDIR /src
    COPY ["Project/Project.csproj", "Project/"]
    RUN dotnet restore "./Project/Project.csproj"
    COPY . .
    WORKDIR "/src/Project"
    RUN dotnet build "./Project.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build
    
    FROM build AS publish
    ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
    RUN dotnet publish "./Project.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false
    
    FROM base AS final
    WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
    COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
    ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
        AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

However, the issue is that the operating system in this setup is Debian, but I need it to run on Alpine. When I try to modify the Dockerfile for Alpine, the project fails to work.
#Parameters
ARG dotnetsdkversionalpine=8.0.401-alpine3.20 
WORKDIR /src
# Build stage
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:$dotnetsdkversionalpine AS build
WORKDIR /src
RUN apk add --no-cache bash wget
# Verify dotnet is available

RUN dotnet --version
# Copy the project file and restore dependencies
WORKDIR /src
COPY Project/Project.csproj Project/
RUN dotnet restore Project/Project.csproj
# Copy the rest of the files and build the project
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Project"
RUN dotnet build Project.csproj -c Release -o /app/build
# Publish the application
RUN dotnet publish Project.csproj -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false
# Final stage using the base image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:$dotnetsdkversionalpin AS final
WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
COPY --from=build /app/publish .
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true \
    AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType=Files \
    FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME=dotnet-isolated \
    FUNCTIONS_SECRETS_PATH=/home/site/wwwroot

Is it possible to run my Azure Functions (which are now compatible with the .NET 8 isolated worker model) on Alpine? If so, how can I achieve this?

Can you share the error you are getting?

When I attempt to send a request to an HTTP-triggered function, I receive a 404 error with no additional error content.

is docker container port mapped with host port?

Whether its mapped or not, its not working. @VivekVaibhavShandilya

the issue is with the  image you are using to execute function code you need to use mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/* images.  you need to use cr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated images for final.
these are the available images for azure function. https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-docker

you can use alpine image for build but for final you need to use azure function image as these images comes with inbuild azure function tools to run function triggers

The error is throwing because you are using wrong image for running Azure function.
To execute azure function you need to have Azure Function Core Tools. Normal dotnet isolated images can't be used to execute Azure functions.
mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/* images comes with inbuilt Azure function core tools to execute the azure function codes.
For Reference you can check all available images for Azure Function here
Normal images can be used for build the files but to execute it function images are required.
Below docker file worked for me.  I am using the 8.0.401-alpine3.20 only for build.
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated:4-dotnet-isolated8.0 AS base
WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
EXPOSE 8080

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0.401-alpine3.20 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["FunctionApp2/FunctionApp2.csproj", "FunctionApp2/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./FunctionApp2/FunctionApp2.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/FunctionApp2"
RUN dotnet build "./FunctionApp2.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./FunctionApp2.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

OUTPUT:



Yes, it works very well but when you look at the operating system information, you can see that it works on Debian 12, not Alpine. Because the image you used is based on Debian. I need to do that on Alpine.
You can see OS info of the image you use is: https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/azure-functions-dotnet-isolated

@bugracetin Currently those are the only images available for azure function. alpine images are not available yet.
